# Angularjs: share data between pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I need to share data between two different pages (login.html and index.html).
I defined a service as follows:

```
.service('loginData', function LoginData(){
        var userData = '';
        this.addUser = function(name){
            this.userData = name;
            //return userData.user;
        }
        this.loggedUser = function(){
            return this.userData;
        }
})
```

the controller defined for login.html:

```
.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'loginData', function($scope, $http, $window, loginData){

    $scope.btnsubmit = function(username,password){

        //scope.user = data_to_send;
        var doc = [];
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/authenticate',{user: username, pwd: password}            )
            .success(function(response) 
            {
                console.log('1 : ' + response);
                if (response != null){
                    console.log('2 : ' + angular.fromJson(response).user);
                    doc = angular.fromJson(response);
                    loginData.addUser(doc[0].user);
                    console.log(doc[0].user);
                    // if I call loginData.LoggedUser here -> it works
                }
            }).error(function()
            {
                console.log('error')
            });

        $window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
}])
```

the controller defined for index.html

```
.controller('profileCtrl', function(loginData){

    console.log(loginData.loggedUser());

})
```

If I call the function loginData.loggedUser inside the login controller, it works well. On the other hand, calling the same function from the index controller it returns undefined.
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to log it before it is defined.  IE the index controller is logging the userdata before the login controller has finished populating it.  THe only reason you are getting undefined rather than '' is because userData is initially defined as a var rather than as part of this (e.g. this.userdata="";)

Answer (score 0):

Services are singletons in angular, so first of all, I would suggest you check `loginData` instance. On the second step, if all instances are fine, you can check the order of running. Most possible, that second controller is initializing before it getting a value, and the reason why you are getting undefined that default value not assigned `var userData = '';` this is a local variable.